# How to find number of one field grouping by another field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nested, aggregation-framework

Assume there is a database of projects; it consists of three field:
1. Project Name
2. Name of person working in that project
3. Role of the person.

We want to calculate within each project, each person has how many roles! The following is a sample:

```
    {
    "Core" : {
        "Ted": 3,
        "Max":1
    },
    "Web" : {
        "Ted":1
    }
    }
```

Which is a result of the following table

```
ProjectName     Person      Role
---------------------------------------------------
Core            Ted         Developer
Core            Ted         Designer
Core            Ted         Manager
Web             Ted         Developer
Core            Max         PCM
```

Comment: how do you store you table thing in your mongodb? you might need to use aggregation framework to get your result.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem! I don't get how to use aggregation... I'm real slow about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregate framework

```
var res = db.test.aggregate([ 
    {$group:{_id:{project:"$ProjectName", name:"$Person"}, Role:{$sum:1}}},
    {$project:{_id:"$_id.project", names:"$_id.name", roles:"$Role"}},
    {$group:{_id:"$_id", record:{$addToSet:{name: "$names", role: "$roles"}}}} 
])

var finalResult = {'final':1};
for(var i in res.result){ 
    var project ={'seq':i};
    for(var j in res.result[i].record {
        project[res.result[i].record[j].name]=res.result[i].record[j].role;
    }
    finalResult[res.result[i]._id]=project;
}
printjson(finalResult)
```

will render a result like:

```
{
    "final" : "1",
    "Web" : {
        "seq" : "0",
        "Ted" : 1
    },
    "Core" : {
        "seq" : "1",
        "Ted" : 3,
        "Max" : 1
    }
}
```

But I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do it. This one is just ok.

Comment: How can I filter those roles without name! They appear as
`{
  "role":1
}`
 How can I filter them out, and no appearance of them.

Comment: @Ace I tried to provide a solution. But actually I'm not quite familiar with mongo shell, there could be simpler and better ways to do it.